# Github: Using multiple forks/clones in new repository (long)

Tags: github

I'm obviously new to GitHub, and want to make sure I do things right before I dive in.

I want to create a new repository that uses forks/clones from 2 existing projects.
The existing projects are not mine.

So let's say the repo's I want to use are called Repo A from developer 'Da' and Repo B from developer 'Db'

I would fork Repo A, then clone it
I would fork Repo B, then clone it

Here is where it gets fuzzy - I now want to merge the 2 into a new Repo (C).

This is where I get lost - not just regarding how to do this, but more regarding what do I push back up to the forked repos? I assume Repo A doesn't want the Repo C stuff? Or does it?

Also, how do you put the licensing info, and 'credit' to the original developers in Repo 'C' ?

Any help is appreciated. I tried searching for it, but could not find a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

The cleaner way, which would still keep each repo separated while allowing you to record `A` and `B` together, would be to declare a parent repo (`C`), with `A` and `B` as **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html)**.

That will simply put `A` and `B` as subdirectories of `C`, that won't actually merge their codebase together, though.

```
C   => remote: your own C on GitHub
|
--A => remote: forkA on GitHub
|
--B => remote: forkB on GitHub
```

As I explain in "[true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)", you still can make changes directly within the `A` and `B` submodules, while recording the new combined state in `C`.